# Spring Autowired DAO with hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit4, dao, autowired

I have a Spring Maven DAO Project which is packaged into a jar.  It was originally a Spring DAO Ivy project, but I converted it to maven.   This was a legacy project which used Spring 3.2.0 and Hibernate 3.5, and now I created a new project and updated to Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.2.3.Final.   I do try to make sure all my jars were updated.

As it stands, the app builds with maven, and all the java code seems to compile.

This DAO does not use annoted entities, instead it uses a legacy hibernate.cfg.xml file, and a lot of hbm.xml files ... which I hope I can use.   I do not relish the idea of converting the very many entities to annoted entities, and then converting the DAO code.

In any event, with the configuration below, I want to test loading a single DAO to test out the configuration.  But, I get an error message as listed below.   I spent a day researching this on google and here to see if anyone had the exact error.

If I had build a new project from scratch, I would have annoted entities, but I don't have that right now, so I have to tweak the configuration to get this DAO project to work correctly.

here is the error:

```
2013-08-06 13:36:42,834 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext] - <Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@165973ea: startup date [Tue Aug 06 13:36:42 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy>
2013-08-06 13:36:42,881 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] -  <Pre-instantiating singletons in  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6c4fc156: defining beans     [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy>
2013-08-06 13:36:42,912 ERROR [org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager]     
<Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener     [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@667cbde6] to prepare test instance [com.tom.project.dao.AaaaBaseDAOLoaderTest@7977b9b]>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tom.project.dao.AaaaBaseDAOLoaderTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: public com.tom.project.dao.accounting.AccountingAccountDAO  com.tom.project.dao.AaaaBaseDAOLoaderTest.accountingAccountDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tom.project.dao.accounting.AccountingAccountDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at  org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.tom.projct.dao.accounting.AccountingAccountDAO com.tom.project.dao.AaaaBaseDAOLoaderTest.accountingAccountDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tom.project.dao.accounting.AccountingAccountDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tom.project.dao.accounting.AccountingAccountDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 28 more
2013-08-06 13:36:42,928 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext] - <Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@165973ea: startup date [Tue Aug 06 13:36:42 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy>
2013-08-06 13:36:42,928 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6c4fc156: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy>
```

So, here is the applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="pooledDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath*:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tom.project"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>  

<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

and here is the project-infrastructure.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!--  Properties files -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:hibernate.properties</value>
            <value>classpath*:project.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Database Connection Pool -->
<bean id="pooledDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100800"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="201600"/>
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>${project.hibernate.connection.driver_class}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>${project.hibernate.connection.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${project.hibernate.connection.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${project.hibernate.connection.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">
        <value>1000</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--  Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Here is the interface for my DAO:

```
public interface AccountingAccountDAO {
    void delete(AccountingAccount accountingAccountID);
    void persist(AccountingAccount accountingAccountID, User queryUser);
    List<AccountingAccount> getAllByAttribute(String fieldName, String name);
    AccountingAccount getById(int i);
}
```

The implementation of the DAO:

```
@Repository("accountingAccountDAO")
public class HibernateAccountingAccountDAO implements AccountingAccountDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(HibernateAccountingAccountDAO.class);

    @Override
    public void delete(AccountingAccount accountingAccountID)
     {
     }

    @Override
    public void persist(AccountingAccount accountingAccountID, User query2User)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public List<AccountingAccount> getAllByAttribute(String fieldName, String name)
    {
        return null;
     }

     @Override
     public AccountingAccount getById(int i)
     {
         return null;
     }

}
```

And here is the unit test which generates the message:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
{    "classpath*:project-infrastructure.xml","classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class AaaaBaseDAOLoaderTest
{
    @Autowired
    public AccountingAccountDAO accountingAccountDAO;

    public AccountingAccountDAO getAccountingAccountDAO()
    {
        return accountingAccountDAO;
    }

    public void setAccountingAccountDAO(AccountingAccountDAO accountingAccountDAO)
    {
        this.accountingAccountDAO = accountingAccountDAO;
    }

    @Test
    public void initResources()
    {
        accountingAccountDAO.getClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.  The problem with my unit test is that I was using:

```
 @ContextConfiguration(locations =
{"classpath*:project-infrastructure.xml","classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
```

which means this was pulling in the completely wrong applicationContext.xml file, and the wrong project-infrastructure.xml file.

In my Spring DAO app, I made sure I was using an app context file specifically to this project, so I renamed it a unique name:   myproject1-app-context.xml and myproject1-infrastructure.xml file.

In this maven project, the directory structure looks like:

src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/main/resources/spring   <-- where my spring app context files are located

In the unit test I changed the location to:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
{"classpath:/spring/myproject1-infrastructure.xml",
"classpath:/spring/myproject1-app-context.xml"})
```

And once I did that, I stopped getting the autowired error.

I know there is some code or trick to point out the files in my classpath that are being used.  I should use that someday, but at least this solved my problem.

As was previously stated, using @Repository in the DAO class, and removing the definition from the myproject1-app-context.xml file, and I did include:

```
    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tom.project" />
```

This was included in the myproject1-app-context.xml file.

So, I hope this helps someone out sometime ....

Answer (score 0):

You just define your bean twice! One with XML configuration:

```
<bean id="accountingAccountDAO"
    class="com.tom.project.dao.accounting.HibernateAccountingAccountDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and one with `@Repository` annotation

```
@Repository("accountingAccountDAO")
public class HibernateAccountingAccountDAO implements AccountingAccountDAO
```

Remove XML definition to get it worked!

Comment: Unfortunately ... as the previous person stated, he made the same suggestion, and as I explained ... I still get the same error message. It still does not work.  Something else must be missing.

Comment: @tjholmes66: can you update question to your new configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are defining `accountingAccountDAO` in xml and with annotation `@Repository("accountingAccountDAO")`? Remove xml definition and go for annotation!

Comment: I didn't know that this was defining it twice.  I thought that defining the DAO in the XML and in the @Repository was required for configuration.  I did remove the bean id="accountingAccountDAO" from the XML file.   I ran maven to build the jar again, and just redo all the files.   I re-ran the test, and I get the same issue.  I still get the same error.